# No access to internet via DHCP, but works with manual IPs

Tags: ip, network, dhcp, lan, network-access

My DHCP server was giving out IPs in the range 10.0.0.1/24, but I ran out of usable IPs, so I changed the subnet to 10.0.1/21 to have more available addresses, however I am now having a weird problem:

If I connect using DHCP I can access the router's IP address, but I am unable to access the internet.

If I connect with manual IP addresses, even when using exactly the same address and submask that were given by DHCP, I can connect fine to the internet. How could this be possible?

#### DHCP

```
$ echo "dhcp" && ifconfig enp24s0
dhcp
enp24s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.10  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 10.0.7.255
        inet6 fe80::a2f8:c497:50ab:51c8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:d8:61:2e:27:7c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 713773  bytes 891254344 (891.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 458  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 303986  bytes 28920367 (28.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
$ ping 172.217.3.78          
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

#### Manual IPs:

```
$ echo "manual" && ifconfig enp24s0
manual 
enp24s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.10  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 10.0.7.255
        inet6 fe80::7980:a295:f0b2:3c92  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:d8:61:2e:27:7c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 713237  bytes 890642451 (890.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 458  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 303517  bytes 28876751 (28.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.3.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mia07s54-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.3.78): icmp_seq=1 ttl=110 time=56.8 ms
64 bytes from mia07s54-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.3.78): icmp_seq=2 ttl=110 time=56.7 ms
```

In case it is relevant, my router is Unifi Edgerouter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, maybe this was a silly mistake, but in the DHCP server settings there was a field called "router" that I didn't know what it was, so I left it blank and forgot about it. This was the "gateway" IP address. I set that and everything works as expected.

Comment: Glad to hear that you could solve your problem - please don't forget to accept your own answer, so the question doesn't keep popping up forever.

Comment: Yeah, came here to suggest your DHCP server is not providing a gateway/default router. Thanks for following up with the resolution.

Comment: @Zac67 Yeah, there's a 2 day waiting period though.